# Is it possible to lock a certain sobject's insert process?

Tags: apex, trigger

Our scenario to import an amount of data from external service via Javascript into Salesforce system. The amount is from several hundred records a a little more than 1000 records.

Since jsforce isn't able to handle bulk insert, the solution I proposed is to first import the data into a specific data object via a long text area field called payload. Then the trigger on that data object stores the data into actual objects.

This works well for most objects, but for some specific scenario: when PriceBookEntry object has more than 800 records the json payload has to be splitted into two records due to the field length limit. However, when the trigger runs of both records runs at same or close to same time, I am getting a 'unable to obtain exclusive access to this record' error message.

I am wondering if there is a lock mechanism I can apply here to enforce the sequence of execution. Otherwise, platform events can be an option but I don't want to change the whole structure. Using promise at the javascript side can also be a solution but I am trying to resolve the things at Apex side.

Is there any suggestions upon this?

Thanks

Comment: An alternative solution to your original dilemma would be to use multiple long-text fields and spread the data across them if required. I've done this by having Payload_0__c, Payload_1__c, ..., Payload_7__c and 131,072 characters in each. Since the fields have predictable names, it's easy enough to iterate over them and reconstruct the original string.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you'd want to lock the parent first:

```
Pricebook2[] p = [select id from pricebook2 where name = 'xyz' for update];
...
```

Without knowing the precise structure of your JSON, I can't make too many assumptions, but it's safe to say if you perform a lock on the parent records first, you should avoid this error.

If doing this dynamically, make sure you lock any records referenced by a master-detail relationship. If you suspect that your code may take more than 5 seconds or so, you might also need to place the record lock in a try-catch loop to allow enough time to finish:

```
Boolean done = false;
while(!done) {
  try {
    Sobject[] records = database.query(parentLock);
    done = true;
  } catch(QueryException e) {
  }
}
```